# No update app after click on notification

Tags: android, react-native, notifications

I use react native and I writing a native module for notification! so I want to when I click on notification just resume app and no restart
I write below code but this work in first time that app runs and after that every click on notification restart app. what's wrong?

```
      Class cl = null;
      try {
          cl = Class.forName(packageName + ".MainActivity");
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
          //TODO: if you want feedback
      }
      Intent openIntent = new Intent(reactContext, cl);
      openIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
      PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(reactContext, 0, openIntent, 0);

      Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(reactContext)
        .setSmallIcon(smallIconResId)
        .setVibrate(new long[]{0,500})
        .setContentTitle("test")
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setContentText("test is here :)")
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I find answer, I change my manifest and everything is ok now.

```
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"  // <-- add this line
  >
```